# multiple openvpn connections for different browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04, openvpn

I'm trying to use OpenVPN to establish multiple connections so that every browser has its own Ip. I'm trying to do it programatically using selenium but I'll adapt to any other if needed. I'm following this other thread which answers the question that I'm asking:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=175765

But I followed all the steps and the problem is that it's using my router Ip (`it's not using any .ovpn provided although it's connecting properly "Initialization Sequence Completed")`.

Why is using my home router IP address when my IP gateway is ok, my username and interface too from the up.sh file?

Perhaps there's another easier way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to have different IPs per browser. The cheapest and most anonymous way is to use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/).

Another way would be to change the IP on the browser level by using a proxy (such as [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org)). For example, you could set something up with a proxy and SwitchyOmega (a browser extension which also allows you to switch between proxies based on URL).

Here is what it looks like from within Chrome.

[image: SwitchyOmega Default Settings]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is that I want to do it programatically using selenium or pupeteer and with SwitchyOmega I will need to do this things manually which is something I don't want to.